# Approach to populating a php site with database images and data

Tags: php, mysql, html

Currently I created mySQL database with the reference path of images and some additional columns of the database with ID, captions, location etc.

I need to populate a php site with these infomation. An example of the site structure should look like this:

`PICTURE`  (Image with width = 175 height = 200)

`Photo taken with Canon Camera` (Caption)

`Paris` (Location)

As you can see, each image should have a caption and location below the picture.

Depending on the mySQL query, all these images retreived from database should be put side by side.

mySQL query is as follows(using php getimage.php):

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("photodb", $link);
$sql = "SELECT photo_path FROM photo WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_close($link);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo file_get_contents($row['photo_path']);


?>
```

getcaption.php:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("photodb", $link);
$sql = "SELECT caption FROM photo WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_close($link);

echo $row['caption'];

?>
```

I have actually created a css ul with class "grid" for doing this. Currently, my code is as follows:

```
    <ul class="grid">
        <li>
            <p class="image"><img src="getImage.php?id=1" alt="" width="175" height="200" /></p>
            <p class="caption"></p>
            <p class="location"></p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="image"><img src="getImage.php?id=2" alt="" width="175" height="200" /></p>
            <p class="caption"></p>
            <p class="location"></p>

        </li>
```

At the moment, I have two issues.

One - How do i display the caption data in the `<p>` tag?

Two - As you can see, I have defined only two `<li>` at the moment. What if my query returns more than two results? What if i did a mySQL insert elsewhere? Should i do a loop somewhere?

Thank you for looking at my issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("photodb", $link);
$sql = "SELECT id, caption, location FROM photo";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

?>
<ul class="grid">

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
        <li>
            <p class="image"><img src="getImage.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" alt="" width="175" height="200" /></p>
            <p class="caption"><?php echo $row['caption']; ?></p>
            <p class="location"><?php echo $row['location']; ?></p>
        </li>
<?php } // while  ?>
</ul>
```